# Get parents attribute value if child doesn't have a specific attribute value

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I have an xml file in linux that I want to process.
I need to get all ids of a parent nodes based on its children.
Here I want to get all id of 'a' that have 'c' without key "f.g".

```
<a id="11111">
  <b>
    <c key="d.e">stuff1</c>
    <c key="f.g">stuff2</c>
    <c key="j.k">stuff4</c>
  </b>
</a>
<a id="22222">
  <b>
    <c key="d.e">stuff1</c>
    <c key="h.i">stuff3</c>
    <c key="j.k">stuff4</c>
    <c key="l.m">stuff5</c>
  </b>
</a>
<a id="33333">
  <b>
    <c key="c.d">stuff0</c>
    <c key="d.e">stuff1</c>
    <c key="h.i">stuff3</c>
    <c key="j.k">stuff4</c>
    <c key="l.m">stuff5</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

In this case I should be getting 22222 and 33333.
I'm not really sure how to write the xpath for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
//a[not(.//c[@key="f.g"])]/@id
```

which can be translated as: find any node `<a>` which does NOT have a child node `<c>` which itself has an attribute called `key` which itself has an attribute value of "f.g".

Comment: I'm getting this error what does it mean?XPath error : Unfinished literal
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
XPath evaluation failure

Comment: @aedan Hard to tell without seeing the acutal xml; but let's try this: what exactly is the xmllint command you used?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by (not):

```
//a[[not(@key = 'f.g')]]
```

It will return you needed 'a' elements, but I don't know how to get their ids.

Comment: Hmm I found out how to get the IDs but the "not" seems to be not working. This is the xpath I'm currently trying out "//a[./b/c[not[@key='f.g']]]/@id"

Comment: please use '(' and ')' instead of '[' and ']':
"//a[.//c[not(@key='f.g')]]/@id"

Answer (score 1):

@Jack Fleeting's answer is probably the best solution. As an alternative (more consuming) :

```
//c[not(@key="f.g" or preceding-sibling::c[@key="f.g"] or following-sibling::c[@key="f.g"])]/ancestor::a
```

Look for `c` elements where itself, and preceding or following siblings contain an attribute different from `@key="f.g"`. Then select their `a` ancestors.